# MS Access Reports show long numbers as scientific notation only on one PC

Tags: ms-access

I've got a MS Access application that shows long numbers. Our Product ID's ("Item ID's" as they are called) are quite long.
When opening reports in the MS Access there is only one computer in the network that renders it incorrectly. This computer will render the long numbers using the scientific notation, but ALL OTHER computers in the network just show the real/long number.
To make it even more weird: when RDP'ing to that one machine, the numbers show up correctly.

Does anybody know what's going on here?

See screenshot:

[image: long numbers rendered incorrectly]

Comment: This is an identifier, not a number. Make it a text field. (What is "RDP"?)

Comment: RDP = Remote Desktop (protocol) @June7

Comment: I would guess: different default printer drivers or a missing font. On the problem computer, the numbers are rendered differently and don't fit into their text boxes, so Access will switch to scientific format.

Comment: @Andre re: "so Access will switch to scientific format" - I don't recall ever seeing that, I only remember Access displaying `######` if the Form/Report control is not wide enough. Unless newer versions of Access behave differently. (I'm pretty much out of the Access business now.)

Comment: Hm, you may be correct @GordThompson. I was sure I had seen this behavior, but I can't reproduce it with Office 365.

Comment: This is dependent on locale settings. Using RDP, you use the locale and keyboard settings of the client

Comment: @ErikA, when RDPing, numbers display correctly - so is that using settings of 'client'? User working locally on that machine gets scientific notation. Again, I say should be a text field.

Comment: I agree that it should be a text field (for viewing!), but unfortunately it's not my application to manage. I'm just trying to troubleshoot why this is the only system that's messing up the numbers. There must be some common locale and/or keyboard settings that I am missing

Comment: I have seen this issue but can't remember if it was Excel or Access. Can't get this behavior right now in Access. If there is a setting somewhere, I can't find it.